# what is a quick way to add the bootstrap gem in my existing rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

- I'm dealing with some "less" problems.
- the gem said it should take care of the dependencies that deal with the "less" compilation, but it gives errors because its not intepreting "less"
- I know rails is practical, so can someone show me how easy the workflow is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates has a great tutorial on including bootstrap into a rails app [Link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics). You could also just include bootstrap sass

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
bundle install
```